# Attach a .xlsx file in PDF using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pdf, automation

Currently I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro for attaching excel file using the Comments tools present there, but since I have to work with almost hundreds of pdf therefore the manual process becomes a tedious task.

Therefore, I have been trying to automate the process wherein I can a attach a excel file in pdf using python, but as of now haven't found a single reference as how to start the same.

Is this process even possible to automate?